# Ugly horizontal artifacts in Kubuntu 16.10 with Nvidia

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu

OK I know the title seems a bit weird, but let me demonstrate what is happening in my PC with a screen shot, and probably it will be clearer:

[image: Screen shot]

As you can see, I'm using the Breeze Dark theme. But black is not really black, it has some horizontal lines, which I find annoying.

**EDIT**: Now that I view the screen shot from another computer, it displays correctly! So you probably cannot see what I'm talking about, except if you are experiencing the same problem :-(

Things that may help:

- I'm using the KDE backports repo for Kubuntu 16.10, so my KDE Plasma version is 5.8
- My video card is a GeForce GT 620 and I'm using the Nvidia proprietary Driver. The Nouveau driver did not have this issue.
- I have a dual monitor setup. This only happens on the primary monitor, which is connected with HDMI. The secondary monitor, which is older and connected with DVI does not have this problem.

Does anybody else has the same problem? Any workarounds? I know that I can uninstall the proprietary driver, but I would prefer not, because the desktop is much more snappier when I use it. Also, I would prefer not to install a newer driver manually, because when I did that before, the system would break every time the kernel was updated.